# How can I put image in Qt label widget in python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have problem adding image in my Qt label widget.

the image shows when I run my code. But it shows in the new pages. It doesn't shows in the place where I put my label widget in Qt creator.

What is the problem?

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
pic = QtGui.QLabel(dialog)
pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("~/~/~/happy.jpg"))
dialog.show()
ex = Ui_SecDialog()        
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your code works fine for me, check your layout in Qt creator (do you mean Qt Designer, right?)

Comment: So where does it show then? Can you describe your problem more detailed and maybe provide a screenshot?